# Calculate age in JS given the birth date in "dd/mm/yyyy" format

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function in JavaScript to calculate age.
I wrote a function but it does not give accurate age.

```js
function calculateAge(date) {
  var formattedDate = date.split("/")
  var birthdateTimeStamp = new Date(formattedDate[2], [1], formattedDate[0])
  var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
  var difference = currentDate - birthdateTimeStamp;
  var currentAge = Math.floor(difference / 31557600000)
  // dividing by 1000*60*60*24*365.25
  return currentAge
}
```

I try `calculateAge("25/11/1993")` and I don't get accurate age. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Try `formattedDate[1]` instead of `[1]`.

Comment: Assuming a year has 365.25 days _may_ seem like a clever idea, but it gives incorrect results on somebody's birthday. For example, the function will report your age as 28 when running this on November 25, 2022 before 6 AM. Next year, you will not turn 30 until noon. And you'll see yourself turn 31 on November 24, 2024 at 6 PM.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `formattedDate` for `[1]` in the `new Date()` function, so `formattedDate[1]` it should be.

```js
function calculateAge(date) {
  var formattedDate = date.split("/")
  var birthdateTimeStamp = new Date(formattedDate[2], formattedDate[1], formattedDate[0])
  var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
  var difference = currentDate - birthdateTimeStamp;
  var currentAge = Math.floor(difference / 31557600000)
  // dividing by 1000*60*60*24*365.25
  return currentAge
}

var age = calculateAge('25/11/1993');
console.log('My age is', age);
```